# Mathjax failed to load: extensions: ["[Contrib]/a11y/accessibility-menu.js"]

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am using Mathjax in my website and I want to add responsive equations (described [here](https://www.mathjax.org/mathjax-accessibility-extensions-v1-now-available/))extension but then it fails to load mathjax.

The following works fine:

```js
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
    TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"]}
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

But when I try add the extension as

```js
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
  MathJax.Ajax.config.path["Contrib"] = "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/contrib";
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
    TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"]},
    extensions: ["[Contrib]/a11y/accessibility-menu.js"]
  menuSettings: {
    collapsible: true,
    autocollapse: true,
    explorer: true
  }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

then Mathjax doesn't work.

Could anyone help me to find the right configuration please?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.  First, you don't put the `MathJax.Ajax.path...` inside the `MathJax.Hub.Config()` call, since it is a separate function, not a configuration option.  Second, you no longer need to define the Contrib location since v2.7 of MathJax does that for you automatically.  You also don't want to use two separate `extensions` specifications since only the last one will be used and you would lose the values in the first one (so they should be combined).  Finally, since you have specified a configuration file that already include the `tex2jax` extension, as well as both the jax that you are requesting, and also the two TeX extensions, there is no need to use them, either.  So try the following:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
    extensions: ["[Contrib]/a11y/accessibility-menu.js"],
    menuSettings: {
      collapsible: true,
      autocollapse: true,
      explorer: true
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

ans see if that doesn't work for you.